# Seeing light source from its diffracted light

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

Even if the line of sight is blocked by something(like a wall as in figure) will I able to see the light source if I see the diffracted light of the source?[image]

1.Will the observer no. 2 see the light source( considering second observer is in a dark room) ? If then:

2.what will be difference in perception of source by 1st and second observer (excluding intensity)?

Another image:

[image]

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform       So will the observer number 2 will see the mirage!

Comment: The amount of diffraction will depend on the size of the opening as compared to the wavelength of light. If the opening is large enough to be able to see an extended object there will not be much diffraction. If the opening is small, you will just see a bright point of light at the position you left of the opening..

Comment: Suppose the light source were a light bulb.  #1 could see the light bulb itself, its shape, its size, its location, etc.  #2 couldn't see any of that.   #2 would see only light *from* the source, but not the source itself ... a bit like the image you posted.

Comment: @garyp          Why? Don't rays make sense of vision?

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the setup.  I see a source, two observers, and a wall with an opening.   Is there anything else, for example, an atmosphere with a non-uniform density?  If not, then the post linked to by @AccidentalFourierTransform does not apply.

Comment: @garyp           No there is no change in atmosphere, it's just two rooms separated by wall. See the second image.

Comment: the observer will only see a bit of light without any detail of the original image(sun in your case). To see the full image all the rays coming from the sun should have reached the observer. The same diffraction is responsible for the resolution limit of even the best microscopes and telescopes